# FeathersJS TypeScript hook returning boolean

Tags: typescript, hook, feathersjs

I'm trying to create a FeathersJS hook that returns a boolean value to use inside the iff() hook of the "feathers-hooks-common" package. Something like the isProvider() hook of the same package.

My problem is that I'm using the TypeScript version of the feathers cli generated app and when I use the generator to create a new hook, the result is:

```
// Use this hook to manipulate incoming or outgoing data.
// For more information on hooks see: http://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html
import { Hook, HookContext } from '@feathersjs/feathers';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
export default (options = {}): Hook => {
  return async (context: HookContext): Promise<HookContext> => {
    console.log(context);
    return context;
  };
};
```

so I don't know how can I use this generated typescript code to return a boolean value that can be used in the iff() hook.

Is there anyone that knows how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if anybody needs it, I've used this code to return a boolean value in a hook:

```
    // Use this hook to manipulate incoming or outgoing data.
    // For more information on hooks see: http://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html
    import { HookContext } from '@feathersjs/feathers';
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    export default (options = {}) => {
      return async (context: HookContext): Promise<boolean> => {
        //Do whatever you need with context data
        return a_boolean_value;
      };
    };
```

I don't know if this would be "the FeathersJS way" but it works.

Comment: How did you get this to work? When I try and use a hook like this in an iff it's throwing an error.